# Window sizing html css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create something like this :

[webpage example](http://www.alpineartisancoffeeroasters.com/)

[webpage example](https://www.caddis.co/)

However i am not sure how they achieved the re sizing of the div according to the window size. How are they able to set the header within the div to stay in the center in different window size. The picture and the words in the div become bigger after a certain window size , smaller after a certain size. The picture remain hd and not stretched or compressed. Please help.

Comment: Search the web for _responsive web page_, make a first effort yourself and then come back here and post what you got and ask about what is not working and we help you get it right.

Comment: oh okay sure. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rule in css know as `@media` rule.
It can be used as responsive web pages.

For eg.

Css

```
<style>
   body {
      background-color: lightblue;
   }

   @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
      body {
         background-color: lightgreen;
      }
   }
</style>
```

Html

```
<body>
   <h1>Resize the browser window to see the effect!</h1>
   <p>The media query will only apply if the media type is screen and the viewport is 480px wide or wider.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! this is really useful!